# What is the Java equivalent to ASP.NET Http Modules?

Tags: java, asp.net, httpmodule

I'm considering rewriting a small Http Module i made in ASP.NET in Java. Based on a specific URL, the Http Module inserts some HTML on an empty HTML layout, do some basic reformatting, and finally returns the rendered HTML.

Being new to Java web development, what is the equivalent to ASP.NET Http Modules?

Comment: For the templating I'd recommend FreeMarker - http://freemarker.org/ , for reformatting JTidy - http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/ or Dom4j - http://sourceforge.net/projects/dom4j/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of HTTP Modules in ASP.NET would be [Filters](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html) in Java Servlet API 2.3+.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to take a look at the following frameworks if you intend to apply styles and formatting to your pages:

- [SiteMesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/)
- [Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/)

You know, it's a 3rd-party framework world in Java, in contrast to one-party always-Microsoft world in dot NET... first search for a framework that does what you need; then look for comparisons of the 100s of frameworks that you found; then ask a question in a Stackoverflow about which one is better; then get confused by reading the contradicting answers and write your own tool ;-)